# How to properly set the BasedOn in XAML style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this as the style template:

```
<Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton1" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="Normal" Source="/images/dogs/dog1.png"/>
                    <Image Name="Pressed" Source="/images/dogs/dog3.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Image Name="Disabled" Source="images/dogs/dog5.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And now I want another one which is based on the upper one, and this doesn't work:

```
<Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton2" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{DynamicResource myDogToggleButton1}">
    <Setter Property="Normal" Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
    <Setter Property="Pressed" Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
    <Setter Property="Disabled" Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
</Style>
```

The error message I get is:

```
The member "Pressed" is not recognized or is not accessible.
The member "Normal" is not recognized or is not accessible.
The member "Disabled" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

I suspect that my different style calling is wrong, so please point out the error.

Comment: ToggleButton does not has Pressed, Normal, Disabled properties you are trying to set in the style myDogToggleButton2

Comment: Following on from @nit's comment, you cannot set an `Image.Source` in a `ControlTemplate` by using the `Image.Name` property value as a property name in a `setter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Resource**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton1" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Style.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Normal" UriSource="Images/darblue_tab.png"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Pressed" UriSource="Images/img-whitebg.png" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Disabled" UriSource="Images/img-greenbg.png"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="Normal" Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Normal}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <Image Name="Pressed" Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Pressed}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <Image Name="Disabled" Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Disabled}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton2" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Normal" UriSource="Images/img-darkbg.png" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Pressed" UriSource="Images/Screenshot_5.png"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Disabled" UriSource="Images/img-bluebg.png"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}"/>
    <ToggleButton  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton2}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Update**
Using single style.

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}"/>
    <ToggleButton  Height="300" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ToggleButton.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Normal" UriSource="Images/img-darkbg.png" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Pressed" UriSource="Images/Screenshot_5.png"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Disabled" UriSource="Images/img-bluebg.png"/>
        </ToggleButton.Resources>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, easy and without adding a dependency property in the codebehid.

Answer (score 1):

thes solution is to use attached properties since you can not access scoped elements in derived styles

Start by writing a helper class

```cs
class Helper:DependencyObject
{
    public static object GetNormal(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(NormalProperty);
    }

    public static void SetNormal(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NormalProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Normal.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Normal", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public static object GetPressed(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(PressedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPressed(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PressedProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Pressed.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Pressed", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public static object GetDisabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(DisabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisabled(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisabledProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Disabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Disabled", typeof(object), typeof(object), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

then modify your styles as follows. l: will refer to your namespace.

```xml
    <Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton1"
           TargetType="ToggleButton"
           BasedOn="{x:Null}"
           xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="l:Helper.Normal"
                Value="/images/dogs/dog1.png" />
        <Setter Property="l:Helper.Pressed"
                Value="/images/dogs/dog3.png" />
        <Setter Property="l:Helper.Disabled"
                Value="/images/dogs/dog5.png" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="Normal"
                               Source="{TemplateBinding l:Helper.Normal}" />
                        <Image Name="Pressed"
                               Source="{TemplateBinding l:Helper.Pressed}"
                               Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Image Name="Disabled"
                               Source="{TemplateBinding l:Helper.Disabled}"
                               Visibility="Hidden" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Normal"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Pressed"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Normal"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Disabled"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton2"
           TargetType="ToggleButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}"
           xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
        <Setter  Property="l:Helper.Normal"
                 Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
        <Setter Property="l:Helper.Pressed"
                Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
        <Setter Property="l:Helper.Disabled"
                Value="/images/dogs/dog2.png" />
    </Style>
```

**a useful benefit**

a useful benefit of this approach. you can also declare inline values instead of defining new style. eg

```
<ToggleButton l:Helper.Normal="image-normal.jpg" 
              l:Helper.Pressed="image-pressed.jpg" 
              l:Helper.Disabled="image-disabled.jpg" 
              Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}"/>
```

note that I am using the base style, this approach is helpful if you have to create a new style just for a single button.

**Extra**

below is the original template for Toggle button look for `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` and you'll be able to manipulate the property values based on the states i.e. `Normal, Pressed, Disabled` and even more

```xml
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
      <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
              <Grid>
                  <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#3FFFFFFF"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <PointAnimation Duration="0" To="0.7,1" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint)"/>
                                  <PointAnimation Duration="0" To="0.7,0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint)"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                  </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                      <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
                          <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
                          <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                              <Rectangle.Fill>
                                  <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                      <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                              </Rectangle.Fill>
                          </Rectangle>
                      </Grid>
                  </Border>
                  <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                  <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

more info on same here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it seems I can't get it to work :/. I have a class Helper defined like this: `namespace ImageButtonTests
{
    public class Helper : DependencyObject
    { ...all other code you pasted
`
and then in the Styles.xaml I have: `<Style x:Key="myDogToggleButton1" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" xmlns:l="ImageButtonTests">` but all I get is an error: The name Helper does not exist in the namespace "ImageButtonTests". Andy ideas?

Comment: Change it to xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ImageButtonTests" it should work, or define the namespace in the root element eg Window etc

Comment: also please add the namespace to second style too, I missed it in the example. I didn't get error in my test as I have an additional namespace defined at root level. so do please add `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ImageButtonTests"` to both of the style or add it to parent or the root of both styles. I updated it in my answer too.

Comment: Thanx for your help - I upvoted your answer but since Heena's answer is really much easier and I got it working immediately I marked that answer as correct one.

Comment: Indeed I like her approach, I wonder why I didn't come up with that.

Comment: I forgot to mention a benefit of this approach. you can also declare inline values instead of defining new style. eg `<ToggleButton l:Helper.Normal="image-normal.jpg" l:Helper.Pressed="image-pressed.jpg" l:Helper.Disabled="image-disabled.jpg" Style="{StaticResource myDogToggleButton1}"/>`. note that I am using the base style, this approach is helpful if you have to create a new style just for a button.

Comment: Thx for the additional info